How to solve genetic algorithm stagnation in the Zen garden problem?
I have a genetic algorithm problem but I'm stuck in local optimum. As you can see in the snippet, it simply can't solve the problem, no matter how many gens or genomes I add to the generation.
Code:
import random

class ZenGarden:
    def __init__(self, width, height, rocks):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.rock_count = len(rocks)
        self.base_grid = [[0] * width for _ in range(height)]  # Initialize a base grid

        # Place rocks in the base grid as -1
        for x, y in rocks:
            self.base_grid[y][x] = -1

        self.grid = self.copy_garden()
        self.max_fitness = width * height - len(rocks)

        # Place rocks in the garden as -1
        for x, y in rocks:
            self.grid[y][x] = -1  # -1 represents a rock

    def copy_garden(self):
        """Create a copy of the garden grid for each genome."""
        return [row[:] for row in self.base_grid]

    def display_garden(self, grid=None):
        """Display the garden grid."""
        if grid is None:
            grid = self.grid
        for row in grid:
            print(" ".join(f"{' K ' if cell == -1 else f'{cell:3}'}" for cell in row))
        print()

class Gene:
    def __init__(self, garden):
        # Choose a random edge to start from
        width = garden.width
        height = garden.height
        edge = random.randrange(garden.width + garden.width + garden.height +garden.height)

        # Starting from the top edge
        if edge < width:
            self.start = (0, edge)
            self.direction = 'down'

        # Starting from the bottom edge
        elif width <= edge < height + width :
            self.start = (edge - width, width - 1)
            self.direction = 'left'

        # Starting from the left edge
        elif width + height <= edge < width + width + height:
            self.start = (height - 1, 2 * width + height - edge - 1)
            self.direction = 'up'

        # Starting from the right edge
        else:
            self.start = (2 * (height + width) - edge - 1, 0)
            self.direction = 'right'

        self.generate_rotation()

    def generate_rotation(self):
        self.rotation = [
            int(a) for a in bin(random.randrange(1024))[2:].zfill(10)
        ]

class Genome:
    def __init__(self, garden, initialize = True):
        self.original_garden = garden  # Keep a reference to the original garden
        self.garden = ZenGarden(garden.width, garden.height, [(x, y) for y in range(garden.height) for x in range(garden.width) if garden.base_grid[y][x] == -1])
        self.fitness = 0
        self.genes = []

        if initialize:
            for _ in range(garden.width + garden.height + garden.rock_count):
                gene = Gene(self.original_garden)  # Pass the reference to original garden
                self.genes.append(gene)
            self.rake()
            
    def rake(self):
        """Use each gene to rake the garden and calculate fitness."""
        g = self.garden
        monk_id = 0  # Start monk ID from 1

        # Go through each gene (monk)
        for gene in self.genes:
            pos = list(gene.start)  # Current position of the monk
            direction = gene.direction  # The direction the monk is moving in
            ri = 0  # Rotation index

            if g.grid[pos[0]][pos[1]] !=0:
                continue
            monk_id +=1

            # Start raking cells
            while True:
                # If the cell is a rock (-1), stop raking
                g.grid[pos[0]][pos[1]] = monk_id

                if direction == 'up':
                    pos[0] -= 1
                elif direction == 'down':
                    pos[0] += 1
                elif direction == 'left':
                    pos[1] -= 1
                else:
                    pos[1] += 1
                
                if pos[0] not in range(g.height) or pos[1] not in range(g.width):
                    break

                if g.grid[pos[0]][pos[1]] == 0:
                    continue

                # Ak je tam prekazka tak sa vratime...
                if direction == 'up':
                    pos[0] += 1
                elif direction == 'down':
                    pos[0] -= 1
                elif direction == 'left':
                    pos[1] += 1
                else:
                    pos[1] -= 1

                # ...a vyberieme ine policko
                if direction == 'up' or direction == 'down':
                    n = (
                        [pos[0], pos[1] - 1],
                        [pos[0], pos[1] + 1],
                    )
                else:
                    n = (
                        [pos[0] - 1, pos[1]],
                        [pos[0] + 1, pos[1]],
                    )
                nv = []
                for p in n:
                    try:
                        nv.append(g.grid[p[0]][p[1]])
                    except IndexError:
                        nv.append('e')

                # Ak je len jedno nepohrabane tak ho vyberieme
                if nv.count(0) == 1:
                    pos = n[nv.index(0)]

                # A ak su dve tak jedno vyberieme
                elif nv.count(0) == 2:
                    # Create a mapping of directions to indices in `n`
                    direction_map = {
                    'up': 0,    # Choose the first element from `n` for 'up'
                    'down': 1,  # Choose the second element from `n` for 'down'
                    'left': 0,  # Choose the first element from `n` for 'left'
                    'right': 1  # Choose the second element from `n` for 'right'
                    }

                    # Use the direction_map to get the correct index
                    pos = n[direction_map[gene.direction]]
                    ri += 1
                    if ri == len(gene.direction):
                        ri = 0

                # Ak ani jedno nie je nepohrabane tak koncime
                else:
                    # Ak sme skoncili v strede mapy tak uz sa neda pokracovat
                    # na dalsi gen
                    if 'e' not in nv:
                        self.set_fitness()
                        return
                    break

                # Nastavime novy smer pohybu
                if direction in ('up', 'down'):
                    direction = 'left' if n.index(pos) == 0 else 'right'
                else:
                    direction = 'up' if n.index(pos) == 0 else 'down'

            self.set_fitness()

    def set_fitness(self):
        """Calculate the fitness as the number of raked cells."""
        self.fitness = sum(1 for x in sum(self.garden.grid, []) if x > 0 )  # Count only raked cells

    def crossover(self, other):
        """Create a new genome by crossing over genes from two parents."""
        new = Genome(self.original_garden)

        # Randomly choose the crossover type
        p = random.random()
        if p < 0.30:
            # One-point crossover: take part from the first parent, part from the second
            point = random.randrange(len(self.genes))
            new.genes = self.genes[:point] + other.genes[point:]
        elif p < 0.60:
            # Uniform crossover: randomly choose genes from either parent
            new.genes = [random.choice([self.genes[i], other.genes[i]]) for i in range(len(self.genes))]
        else:
            # Full copy: take all genes from one parent
            new.genes = random.choice([self.genes, other.genes])

        # Mutations: new gene generation or rotation regeneration
        for i in range(len(new.genes)):
            p = random.random()
            if p < 0.2:  # 5% chance to generate a new gene
                new.genes[i] = Gene(self.original_garden)
            elif p < 0.05:  # 10% chance to regenerate rotations
                new.genes[i].generate_rotation()

        # After crossover, rake the garden with the new genome
        new.rake()

        return new
def rank_selection(population):
    """Rank selection to select parents based on their fitness."""
    # Sort the population based on fitness (higher fitness first)
    sorted_population = sorted(population, key=lambda x: x.fitness, reverse=True)
    
    # Assign ranks and calculate probabilities for selection
    total_ranks = sum(range(1, len(population) + 1))  # Sum of all ranks
    probabilities = [rank / total_ranks for rank in range(1, len(population) + 1)]

    # Select a genome based on the rank probabilities
    selected = random.choices(sorted_population, weights=probabilities, k=2)
    return selected[0], selected[1]  # Return two selected parents for crossover


def solve_hybrid_selection(rocks, width=12, height=10):
    """Solve the ZenGarden problem using hybrid selection (rank selection + crossover)."""
    garden = ZenGarden(width, height, rocks)
    population_size = 100
    generations = 1000  # Run for 1000 generations
    population = [Genome(garden) for _ in range(population_size)]
    
    for gc in range(generations):
        best = max(population, key=lambda x: x.fitness)
        next_generation = [best]  # Preserve the best genome
        
        # Hybrid strategy: 60% crossover, 40% direct rank selection
        num_crossover = int(0.6 * (population_size - 1))
        num_rank_selected = population_size - 1 - num_crossover
        
        # Generate offspring by crossover (60%)
        for _ in range(num_crossover):
            parent1, parent2 = rank_selection(population)
            child = parent1.crossover(parent2)
            next_generation.append(child)
        
        # Select remaining directly from rank selection (40%)
        for _ in range(num_rank_selected):
            parent, _ = rank_selection(population)
            next_generation.append(parent)
        
        population = next_generation

        # Print generation stats
        print(f'Generation: {gc + 1}, Best Fitness: {best.fitness}/{garden.max_fitness}')

        # Check if the best genome solved the garden
        if best.fitness == garden.max_fitness:
            print("Solution found!")
            garden.display_garden(best.garden.grid)
            break
    else:
        print(f"No solution found after {generations} generations. Missing {garden.max_fitness - best.fitness}")
        garden.display_garden(garden.grid)
        garden.display_garden(best.garden.grid)

# Example usage
rocks = [(5, 3), (2, 6), (9, 1), (3, 1), (8, 6), (9, 6)]
solve_hybrid_selection(rocks)

I've tried a lot of mutation probabilities and adding new selection methods but I simply can't get over it.
